# Add variable to rule before execution

Tags: 7, rules

I'm looking for a way to alter the variables before a rule is executed. Specifically, I'm trying to add a list of users who should be notified of a new comment so that I can create a loop and send an email to each.

I have implemented `hook_rules_event_info_alter` as follows:

```
function mymodule_rules_event_info_alter(&$events)
{
    $events['comment_insert']['variables']['affected_users'] = array('type' => 'list<user>', 'label' => 'Anyone that should be notified about a new comment.');
}
```

However, I am at a loss as to which hook needs to be implemented in order to fill in this variable before it is used. (On my site the default will be the node author, however there are some nodes where several users should be notified).

Answer (score 0):

The implementation should be placed into the file `MODULENAME.rules.inc`, which gets automatically included when the hook is invoked.

Comment: Thanks @monymirza, but what sort of implementation are we talking about? Can you provide a link to an example? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I discovered I don't actually need to create my own variable to do this, instead I can add the list of members via the views conditions. Select 'Entity has field' and choose you list field. Now when you add a loop, the field will come up in the data selectors.